# Why angular still encode request as JSON? ( $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike )

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I want to angular to make `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests **by default**. Not JSON.

*angular **1.4.5***

This doesnt work.

```
 angular.module('APP').config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $httpProvider.defaults.paramSerializer = '$httpParamSerializerJQLike';
    }]);
```

even when I add this after:

```
angular.module('APP').run(['$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  $http.defaults.paramSerializer = $httpParamSerializerJQLike;
}]);
```

But works when i use it directly in service/controller when making requests.
as:

```
$http.post('/auth', $httpParamSerializerJQLike({email: email, pwd: pwd}))
.then(...
```

Now i use This interceptor:  (bad code, wrond way, but works as I want)

```
angular.module('APP').factory('ApiInterceptor', ['$q', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
function($q, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      $rootScope.loading = true;
      if (config.method === "POST"){
        if (config.data === undefined) config.data = {};
        config.data = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(config.data);
      }
      return config || $q.when(config);
    }
  };
}]);
```

How can i configure whole app to use x-www-form-urlencoded without bicycles as `$.param` interceptors etc.

Comment: **yes** . Content-Type header exists, and its correct, but serializer still doesn't work.

Comment: still looking for answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaults.paramSerializer` only used by URL building, not the `POST` body, the `defaults.transformRequest` is what you're looking for

Comment: Now i use middleware and json request works great. Thanks, i'll try and ckeck right answer if you are right.